# How to highlight a cell data (formed using an array) based on some results in FPDF

Tags: php, cell, fpdf

I want to highlight specific cell based on results in FPDF. I am displaying cells using array.

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
foreach($a as $col)
$pdf->Cell(32,10,$col,1,0,'C');
```

Each of these array values are basically results. So for example

```
if result == 3
```

I want cell 3 that has 3 written in it can highlight in some manner(advice is welcomed) I thought about making a circle there or changing cell background/border colour or changing text colour.

I tried something like this but it does not work

```
if(in_array(3,$a ,TRUE)){
 $pdf->SetFillColor(128, 0, 0);
 $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Can somebody give me hints only through FPDF and php please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that you only want to fill the array value that equals 3, this is how you could do it:

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
foreach($a as $col) {
    if ($col == 3) {
       $pdf->SetFillColor(128, 0, 0);
       $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);
    } else {
       $pdf->SetFillColor(255);
       $pdf->SetTextColor(0);
    }
    $pdf->Cell(32,10,$col,1,0,'C');
}
```

The `if (in_array(3, $a))` wouldn't work because by saying that you are setting the fill and text color for all if there is a 3.

Comment: thank you so much :-) it worked.  really appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the if guard, better yet remove it altogether and test the background color code

```
if(true){
 $pdf->SetFillColor(128, 0, 0);
 $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);
}
```